# merge data frames "not a slot in class data.frame"

Tags: r, r-sp

I use the book "A practical guide to geostatistical mapping" from T. Hengl, which also offers the [code](http://spatial-analyst.net/book/meuse.R) to reproduce the results. Unfortunately, loads of the code contained is deprecated or even defunct. I was able to restore most of the code, but now I'm stuck with something seemingly simple: merging two data frames. My error:

```
Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  :   ‘data’ is not a slot in class “data.frame”
```

Here the code to reproduce that error:

```
library(gstat)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

# load the data:
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
download.file("http://spatial-analyst.net/book/system/files/meuse.zip", destfile=paste(getwd(), "meuse.zip", sep="/"))
grid.list <- c("ahn.asc", "dist.asc", "ffreq.asc", "soil.asc")
# unzip the maps in a loop:
for(j in grid.list){
  fname <- unzip("meuse.zip", file=j)
  print(fname)
  file.copy(fname, paste("./", j, sep=""), overwrite=FALSE)
}

# load grids to R:
meuse.grid <- readGDAL(grid.list[1])
# fix the layer name:
names(meuse.grid)[1] <- sub(".asc", "", grid.list[1])
for(i in grid.list[-1]) {
  meuse.grid@data[sub(".asc", "", i[1])] <- readGDAL(paste(i))$band1
}
names(meuse.grid)
proj4string(meuse.grid) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")

meuse.ov <- over(meuse, meuse.grid)
str(meuse.ov)
meuse.data <- meuse[c("zinc", "lime")]@data
str(meuse.data)
meuse.ov@data <- merge(meuse.ov, meuse.data)
```

This is really confusing, as both data frames (meuse.ov and meuse.data) seem identical in their structure:

```
> str(meuse.ov)
'data.frame':   155 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ ahn  : int  3214 3402 3277 3563 3406 3355 3428 3476 3522 3525 ...
 $ dist : num  0.00136 0.01222 0.10303 0.19009 0.27709 ...
 $ ffreq: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ soil : int  1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 ...
```

and

```
> str(meuse.data)
'data.frame':   155 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ zinc: num  1022 1141 640 257 269 ...
 $ lime: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I tried resolving this with looking things up on stackoverflow, but nothing did work. The (not working) legacy code in the book suggested this (for your understanding maybe):

```
meuse.ov <- overlay(meuse.grid, meuse)
meuse.ov@data <- cbind(meuse.ov@data, meuse[c("zinc", "lime")]@data)
```

Comment: It has to do with the fact that you use `@` on a data frame. `@` is generally used to access slots, which data frames don't have.Try `foo <- cbind(meuse.ov, meuse.data)` instead.

Comment: What is the "@" operator? Shouldn't you be using "$" as it's just a data.frame?

Comment: meuse.grid is a SpatialPointDataFrame with coordinates, thus the structure here is more complidated with a nested structure and 5 "slots". Check `str(meuse.grid)`. This shouldn't be the issue imo.

Comment: `meuse.grid` does indeed have slots and can have slots. However, both `mouse.ov` and `mouse.data` are regular data frames that cannot have slots. That's why you are getting an error that `@data` is not a slot in the class `data.frame`. Edit: To be more complete: `meuse.grid` is an S4 object (try `isS4(meuse.grid)`).

Comment: Wow! I always thought it doesn't matter in R what you have infront of the assignment operator (<-)...apparently it does matter! Lessons learned, thanks!

Comment: No problem! I flagged the thread as needing to be closed because "the solution was a simple typographic error", just to ensure that people know the question has been answered. Edit: Also, @PawełSopel, you will find answers if you read up on S3 and S4 objects (the differences between them).